# Can we use Tries to Decode a Huffman code

Tags: java, data-structures, decoding, huffman-code

Given a set of characters and their corresponding Huffman encoded string. Can we use tries to decode them?

I have the following class which illustrates my approach. I did try a few test cases over the internet but I am not completely satisfied with what I found.

This is a test case I found over the internet 'geeksforgeeks' and its corresponding encoded string is given in the main method as an argument for my search function. This test case seems to work fine. Can someone explain why we can or why we cannot use tries?

```
public class HuffmanDecode {
    static class Code {
        Character c;
        Code[] children;
        boolean isEnd;
        public Code(){
            this.c = null;
            this.children = new Code[2];
            this.isEnd = false;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++){
                children[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    static Code root;
    static StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    public static void buildTree(String input, Code current, char ch){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++){
            char curr = input.charAt(i);
            int index = curr - '0';
            if(current.children[index] == null){
                current.children[index] = new Code();
            }
            current = current.children[index];
        }

        current.isEnd = true;
        current.c = ch;
    }

    public static String search(String input, Code current){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length(); i++){
            char curr = input.charAt(i);
            int index = curr - '0';
            if(current!=null && current.isEnd){
                str.append(current.c);
                current = root;
                i--;
            }
            else if(current.children[index]!=null && !current.isEnd){
                current = current.children[index];
            }

        }
        if(current!=null && current.isEnd)str.append(current.c);
        return str.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HuffmanDecode obj = new HuffmanDecode();
        HashMap<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        root = new Code();
        map.put('e',"10");
        map.put('f',"1100");
        map.put('g',"011");
        map.put('k',"00");
        map.put('o',"010");
        map.put('r',"1101");
        map.put('s',"111");

        map.forEach((key, value)->{
            obj.buildTree(value,root,key);
        });
        search("01110100011111000101101011101000111",root);
        System.out.println(str.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an ideal use case for a trie. What's the problem you are having with it?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm if my approach will work for all test cases provided the given format for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a Trie can be used to encode and decode characters into bit representations, provided that it is a binary tree. A trie without a binary structure will not be decodable due to the fact that, while parsing through the potential character values for each node in the trie, there could be characters that end up being unreachable due to the fact that they share a prefix with a character represented by a node higher up in the trie structure. For example, if a B is represented with the code 001, and a C is represented with the code 001111, there is no way for the decoding algorithm to reach the node representing the letter C due to the fact that it will return whenever it reaches the parent value, B. This would make it impossible to decode any statement containing the letter C, and therefore render the non-binary trie ineffective at encoding or decoding a set of Huffman encoded characters. Given a binary trie, however, each node representing a character would be represented as a leaf value within the trie, meaning that every encoded character will have a "prefix code" ensuring that there is no character represented in any of its parent nodes -- and thereby assuring that the character representation can be reached by the decoding algorithm.